# How to pass passport facebook data to angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, passport.js

I am using passport facebook for user authentication in my web app. My Node backed is running on localhost:8080 and angular frontend is running on localhost:4200. How can I save the data received from Facebook, Save it to a database and then pass that database data to my angular frontend? I tried so many guides and tutorials online, all of those are running on the same domain, but mine is different domains(8080 & 4200).

Below is my social auth code, if it can be of any help.

```
    module.exports = function(app, db) {



var express          = require('express'),
        ObjectID         = require("mongodb").ObjectID,
        passport         = require('passport'),
        FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
        GoogleStrategy   = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy,
        LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin');

    var authConfig      = require('../config/socialConfig');


    var session = require('express-session');

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { secure: false }
    }))

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: authConfig.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret:authConfig.facebookAuth.clientSecret ,
        callbackURL: authConfig.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
    },
        function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            console.log("Hello" + profile);
            // User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
              // if (err) { return done(err); }
              // done(null, user);
            // });
            done(null, profile);
        }
    ));


    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }));

    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));

    }
```

And below is my frontend link to facebook auth

```
<a href="/auth/facebook" target="_blank">Facebook Login</a>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Looking forward to some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you Node.js app is on the other port, you need to specify the full URL to the /auth/facebook API (http://localhost:4020/auth/facebook).

Also, quoting the another post:

> For two documents to be considered to have the same origin, the protocol >(http/https), the domain and the port (the default 80 or :xx) have to be >indentical

So you need to enable CORS on your node.js server. An easy way to do it is to use Express-cors npm

```
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
```